# How can I have ONE views-view-fields-VIEW_NAME--page.tpl.php for multiple views?

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have 10 content types and they all have page view. These content type have similar fields and the difference is just their name, that is why I don't want to create the following files for every one of them:

- views-view--VIEWNAME--page.tpl.php
- views-view-fields-VIEW_NAME--page.tpl.php

One of the views is called sabk_zendegi, and the following code belongs to views-view--sabk_zendegi--page.tpl.php.

```
<div><img src="<?php print $directory; ?>/image/view_tpl_file/top_border.png" /></div>
<?php print $rows; ?> 
<?php print $pager; ?>
<div><img src="<?php print $directory; ?>/image/view_tpl_file/bottom_border.png"/></div>
```

This is not a good idea to repeat the same code for 10 files which the only difference is just their name. I have the same problem for views-view-fields--sabk_zendegi--page.tpl.php; this code belongs to views-view-fields--sabk_zendegi--page.tpl.php.

```
<div id="whole_field" style="clear:both;">
<div style="border:1px solid #97857b">
    <?php print $fields['field_sabk_zendegi_photo']->content; ?>
</div>
<div style=";text-align: right;width:540px">
    <div style="margin-top:0;">
    <ul style="padding-right: 0;margin-right: 15px;">
    <li style="list-style-image: url('<?php print $directory; ?>/image/view_tpl_file/list_item.png')">
    <?php print $fields['field_sabk_zendegi_titr']->content; ?>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php print $fields['field_summary']->content; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see this code is the same for all the views but the difference is just the `$fields` fields. (It can be replaced by a variable that is already assigned in template files.)

Is there any preprocess/template function in Drupal 7 that calls one page for views-view--VIEWNAME--page.tpl.php and one page for views-view-fields--VIEWNAME--page.tpl.php and it assigns the relevant variables inside it?

Instead of using `$field['fields_summary']`, I should be able to use `$summary` in this new general page, and these variables have their values already assigned by template/preprocess function according to the view.